# How to check email id is existing or not using ajax in php?

Tags: php, ajax

I have to check email id is existing or not. I know this question is ask server time and I also checked on google but still getting the issue. I have tried some code but I don't know where I am wrong. Would you help me in this?

```
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <div id="status"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#email").keyup(function() {
        var name = $('#email').val();
        if(name=="")
        {
            $("#status").html("");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: "email="+ name ,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#status").html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Process.php**

```
/*Checking email available or not*/
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $chk_email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql=" SELECT Email FROM request WHERE Email='$chk_email'";
    $result_email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn->query($sql));

    if($result_email==0){
        echo "<span style='color:green;'>Available</span>";         
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<span style='color:red;'>Already register</span>";    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to post data like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: {email: name},//<--- Look here
    success: function(html){
        $("#status").html(html);
    }
});
```

Oh and in your php code use `mysqli_escape_string` to escape the strings to avoid mysql injections.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Zeus, I tried but still no action taking

Comment: @NarendraVerma put a `alert(html);` line in success function to see what is actually being returned. If alert doesn't gets called at all then that means there is some problem with posting data maybe url.

Comment: Yes, I added alert(html); no output return

Comment: @NarendraVerma does alert function gets called at all or alert function gets called but the popup is blank. I just tested the ajax code, it just works fine.

Comment: Yes, Mr.Zeus I found the issue. My jQuery script was not working. I need one more help. I have to set time interval because If I entered one character then is directly displaying available. I have to display a message after 5sec. Is it possible then where should I add it?

Comment: @NarendraVerma I would recommend adding a button saying "Check availability" and run ajax function on click of that button instead of key up function.

Comment: Sure,So I have to use $("button-name").click(function() {     instated of $("#email").keyup(function() {    this?

Comment: @NarendraVerma yes sir

Comment: Mr.Zeus, Can we animate whatever output(Available or not available) is coming from process page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137283/discussion-between-zeus-and-narendra-verma).